# How to create missing `clean` target for header-only library?

Tags: cmake

In my header-only library I have the following `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

project(Math)
set(PROJECT_VERSION 0.1)

# Install prefix
if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX)
    set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX /usr/local)
endif()
message("++ Installation prefix set to \"${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}\"")

configure_file("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/pkg-config.pc.cmake"
               "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.pc")

install(DIRECTORY include/ DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/include/Math")
install(FILES       "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.pc"
        DESTINATION "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/share/pkgconfig/")
```

It works normally, but it appears that when I say `make clean` (which I expect to be a no-op, but for which `make` should return 0), I get

```
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop.
make: *** [clean] Error 2
```

I see that there does exist a `clean` target in `Makefile` in the build dir, but it calls for a `clean` target in `CMakeFiles/Makefile2`, where it doesn't exist.

I've found that the target is created if I add the following to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_custom_target(clean)
```

But then I get some annoying warnings for any `make` invocation:

```
Makefile:150: warning: overriding commands for target `clean'
Makefile:123: warning: ignoring old commands for target `clean'
```

I.e. for some reason the `Makefile` gets two instances of `clean` target.

How can I create a no-op `clean` target cleanly, not getting any warnings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
add_custom_target(dummy_target)
```

works for me: `make clean` doesn't issue any error.

Because `ALL` is not used for custom target, it doesn't appear during `make` invocation.